# gpo ie user force update

Tags: active-directory, proxy, group-policy, internet-explorer

We use two 2008 Domain-Controllers and one 2012 DC

In a gpo we set the proxy for IE-11 per user. eg: X use proxy, server: proxyserver, port: 3131
This gpo is not mandatory, so users could change proxy.

Recently our proxy changed to port: 8080

I am encountering a spurious behaviour ...some users get the old settings, some none, some the new settings... and it seems older settings keep re-appearing after manual changing to the new ones.

I saw problems in the AD-replication, which are now solved.

But my main question is:
IF a user can change settings, and has changed settings - will my new settings (in gpo) override the user-changed-settings?
eg: user has set port to 1234, - later I set the gpo which is applying to him (tested) to 8080.. but still they do not apply when he logs on.

manually executing gpupdate works.
Should I write logon script to execute gpudate ? (we have 1100 users)

Comment: What version of Windows and Internet Explorer are your clients running?